# Getting Illegal state exception for @Transient property in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persist, transient

I have one property in Model class which is having @transient property,I have used this annotation because I don't want it to persist with database. But in the query in DaoImpl class I have used it in select clause. So this gives me `:java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode`

What could be the reason? I don't want to remove @transient annotation.

```
    public class Hello implements Serializable{
    @JsonIgnore
    private String new;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String wanted;

}
```

query in DaoImpl class

```
SELECT new,wanted from Hello
```

Comment: Transient is not saved in DB. Read documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use a transient property inside your query.

The whole meaning of transient is that DB is not aware of this property

Comment: But there is column for that property in the table. I want to fetch that column,but don't want to save any changes and updates made for that particular column in the front end to reflect in the DB. With out using that property in the query how would I get it to the front end?

Comment: That's something you should ask as a new question. And as a hint: check `@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)` before asking

Answer (score 0):

Transient means that hibernate will not even try to save it in the db, so if it is not saved then it cannot be used in queries. If you check the db you will find that there is no value entered for this field and it should not even exist as a column there. It only lives in the code.

Answer (score -2):

By default, all fields in your class will be persisted to the database if possible. If there is a field that should not be recorded in the database, we mark that field with the @Transient annotation. Hence data won't be saved which eventually means getting the data won't be possible

This is what I meant

Comment: That's exactly opposite to what you said.